# Mongoose: find with multi condition

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am now studying node.js.
Then I have some problem.
I have created a new model - "adventuremodel".
And I want to search data from it with multi condition.
My code as following:

adventureModel.find({ $and : [{ name : new RegExp(name, 'i'), description : new RegExp(description, 'i'), tags : { $in : tags } }]}, function (err, adventures) {});

But it not works fine.
How can I find with multi condition at the same time?

Please help me.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried $regex from MongoDB?

Comment: yes. I have some code that works fine as following: adventureModel.find({ $or : [ {name : new RegExp(term, 'i')}, {description : new RegExp(term, 'i')}, {tags : { $in : tags } } ] }, function (err, adventures) {});

Comment: Now you're using *term* instead of *name*. Is that correct? Can you also provide some data that I can import?